# Logout user in an excluded VerifyCsrfToken route in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

i recently developed a laravel application integrated with webmoney
webmoney use POST to callback data from gateway
i have added the specified route in $except array in VerifyCsrfToken middleware
but i cannot get the current user in that route and then i figured out user has been logged out

would you please help me fix this ?

Comment: you can try using this method to access user id in api middleware:`auth('api')->user();`

Comment: @sta didnt work

Answer (score 0):

For resolving this problem you need in `config/session` set `SameSite` to `null` or `none`
For avoiding security issue it's better to set secure to true